# Movie about aliens that secretly invade earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

A movie I watched when I was younger (about 2010ish) was about a woman finding out about a secret alien invasion. They look and act like humans but they can't show emotion, so that's how survivors end up hiding amongst the aliens.

There were two scenes I remember: the lady gets on a subway or bus panicking about the aliens and a black guy next to her tells her to hide her emotions and that's how he has been living just fine. Another scene is when there's some special gala or dance or something for politicians/elite where the aliens dressed as waiters barf into the bowl of fruit punch(?) to serve everyone so they get infected and become like them.

Comment: Do you remember the conversion to alien necessarily involving sleep? And a weird sloughing of rubbery skin?

Comment: Yep thats the one, another guy answered it also, its the invasion with Nicole Kidman I was thinking of

Comment: Congrats on 100+ rep! That unlocks a lot of things on the site including comments and chat, IIRC. And also, thank you very much for accepting the answer. Sadly, we often never get proof that the correct answer was provided.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this might be 2007's *[The Invasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invasion_(film))*, starring Nicole Kidman, another retread of the Body Snatchers. The trailer for it, IIRC, showed a black man on a subway car telling Nicole she can fool the aliens by not showing emotion; this was followed by a scene where a pod person walks off the roof of a building and when a woman seeing this freaks out other pod people swarm her. Not having seen the whole thing I can't guarantee this is what you're looking for, but it seems to fit what you've described.

### Trailer

Comment: [20% critic score on RT?](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/invasion). sounds reptilian

Comment: It should be noted that this is a remake of "Invasion of the Body Snatchers", which was originally a 1955 novel and was made into 3 earlier movies -- the 1956 version is considered a classic.

Comment: @Barmar- I said as much in my answer.