# Movie about a group of emotionless aliens taking over Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I remember watching a movie about a group of emotionless aliens turning humans into them and trying to take over the world. The protagonist was a mom trying to protect herself and her son from becoming an alien. There was this one scene that I don't remember much, but I think the mom was trying to kill an Asian boy because he was being controlled.

Comment: Invasion of the Body Snatchers?

Comment: No, I remember the movie seeming new, not old.

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate. This is not a censure, just part of our policy/bookkeeping to tie together [tag:story-identification] questions that have the same answer. You will still receive points for upvotes, and people can post comments.

Comment: Yeah, I got it, no worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[The Invasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invasion_(film))* from 2007

> After a Space Shuttle crashes on Earth, an intelligent fungus-like alien lifeform is discovered on shuttle remnants scattered widely over the United States. Once people are infected by the organism, and REM sleep occurs, the organism takes control of its host and reprograms their genetic expression. One of the first people infected is Tucker Kaufman, a CDC director investigating the crash.
>
> Tucker's ex-wife, psychiatrist Carol Bennell, begins to feel something is amiss when people seem to have "changed". Her patient, Wendy Lenk (played by Veronica Cartwright, who appeared in the 1978 film version as Nancy Bellicec), describes how her husband "is not (her) husband", and one of Carol's son's friends acts detached and emotionless.

....

> Ben and Dr. Stephen Galeano, a biologist, discover how the spore takes over the brain during REM sleep. During this investigation, Luddie calls Ben, worried about Yorish's behavior. Ben and Galeano also find that people who had brain-affecting illnesses, such as encephalitis or ADEM, are immune to the spore because their previous illnesses prevent the spore from "latching on" to the brain matter. Oliver is immune to the spore because of the ADEM he had as a young child. Carol decides to retrieve Oliver, who might show a way to a cure, back from Tucker. Before she drives to Tucker's house, she joins Ben's team who is called to the house of the Belicecs, the Czech ambassador and his wife, in a case of emergency. There they witness the transformation of Yorish (the Russian ambassador) and the Belicecs' friend.

### Trailer

I remembered this one from having run into it while searching for another question, and then found it with a search for `film aliens show emotion`

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279495/movie-about-aliens-that-secretly-invade-earth/279500#279500

Comment: Yes, it was this movie.

Comment: @Roberto Glad I could help. Don't forget to click on the checkmark.

Comment: Wasn't this a remake (or at least, re-imagining) of Body Snatchers?

Comment: @AndresF. I don't know if it was acknowledged as such, but it definitely shares DNA.